# Connect to external server over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, portforwarding

I want to connect to local address `127.0.0.1:2222` belonging to a server with IP `172.25.250.10` as user `especial`. The connection would be done from another place in the network. As a tip they have told me to use `ip forwarding` but I cannot manage to succeed.
My approach has been doing:

```
ssh especial@172.25.250.10 -p 2222
```

But this attempt returns:

```
ssh: connect to host 175.25.250.10 port 2222: Connection refused
```

In the `172.25.250.10` the `2222` port is listening for ssh connections

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, use the following to connect to 172.25.250.10 and use local port forwarding for port 2222.

```
ssh -L 2222:localhost:2222 especial@172.25.250.10
```